# obj-c: how to parse a "human friendly" date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I've read a many things about parsing date in obj-c, but I can't find anything dealing with dates like "Mon, 25 Apr 2011 11:53 am CDT"... I'd like to convert it to `NSDate` in a smart way but I'm running out of ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`-[NSDateFormatter dateFromString:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-CJBGJDAE)

You'd probably use `@"EEE, d MMM yyyy hh:mm a zzz"` as your date format string.

And by the way, googling ["convert string to date objective-c"](http://www.google.com/search?q=convert%20string%20to%20date%20objective-c) yields thousands of hits that have correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

NSDateFormatter is a pretty complete class that covers all "human-friendly" date scenarios.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

There's also several questions on stackoverflow that seem very similar to your question, so a quick search should help you out.